# How to nicely plot clipped layered artists in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Consider that you have three artists in a matplotlib plot. What is the easiest way to not show the intermediate-level artist in the bbox of the top-level artist while retaining the low-level artist visible throughout the whole area?

Illustration of what I want to achieve:

[image: Illustration of layered clipping]

It there was no requirement of being able to see the lowest level a non-transparent facecolor of the toplevel plot would be enough. This does not work with the three levels as then the both of the lower levels would be concealed.

See [this IPython notebook for a solution using `shapely`](https://github.com/andim/pysnippets/blob/master/mpl-poly-cutout.ipynb). Here is a not yet completely functional pure `matplotlib` example, but I'm hoping there is a simpler way of getting the same result that I have not thought of yet.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches, cm
from matplotlib.path import Path
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
imdata = np.random.randn(10, 10)
ax.imshow(imdata, extent=(0, 1, 0, 1), aspect='auto', cmap=cm.coolwarm)
text = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Text', fontsize='xx-large', fontweight='bold',
               color='k', ha='center', va='center')
renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
bbox = text.get_window_extent(renderer).transformed(ax.transData.inverted())
bboxrect = patches.Rectangle((bbox.x0, bbox.y0), bbox.width, bbox.height)
bbpath = bboxrect.get_path().transformed(bboxrect.get_patch_transform())
patch = patches.Rectangle((0.3, 0.3), 0.4, 0.4)
path = patch.get_path().transformed(patch.get_patch_transform())
path = Path.make_compound_path(path, bbpath)
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', hatch=r'//')
ax.add_patch(patch)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with another answer that's a bit cleaner: it involves creating a clip mask for the hatched region that has a hole in it, so that you can see *everything* in the background behind it.

```
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

def DoubleRect(xy1, width1, height1,
               xy2, width2, height2, **kwargs):
    base = np.array([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)])
    verts = np.vstack([xy1 + (width1, height1) * base,
                       xy2 + (width2, height2) * base[::-1],
                       xy1])
    codes = 2 * ([Path.MOVETO] + 4 * [Path.LINETO]) + [Path.CLOSEPOLY]
    return PathPatch(Path(verts, codes), **kwargs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
imdata = np.random.randn(10, 10)

# plot the image
im = ax.imshow(imdata, extent=(0, 1, 0, 1), aspect='auto',
               cmap='coolwarm', interpolation='nearest')

# plot the hatched rectangle
patch = plt.Rectangle((0.3, 0.3), 0.4, 0.4, facecolor='none',
                      hatch=r'//')
ax.add_patch(patch)

# add the text
text = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Text', fontsize='xx-large', fontweight='bold',
               color='k', ha='center', va='center')

# create a mask for the hatched rectangle
mask = DoubleRect((0, 0), 1, 1, (0.4, 0.45), 0.2, 0.1,
                  facecolor='none', edgecolor='black')
ax.add_patch(mask)
patch.set_clip_path(mask)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain why the shaded box's lower left corner does not start at (0, 0)? It would be great if you could explain a bit how `DoubleRect()` works. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but I would probably accomplish this by showing the image twice, once in the background, and once with a custom clip path in the foreground. Here's an example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
imdata = np.random.randn(10, 10)

# plot the background image
im = ax.imshow(imdata, extent=(0, 1, 0, 1), aspect='auto',
               cmap=cm.coolwarm, zorder=1)

# plot the hatched rectangle
patch = patches.Rectangle((0.3, 0.3), 0.4, 0.4, facecolor='none',
                          hatch=r'//', zorder=2)
ax.add_patch(patch)

# plot the box around the text
minirect = patches.Rectangle((0.4, 0.45), 0.2, 0.1, facecolor='none',
                             edgecolor='black', zorder=4)
ax.add_patch(minirect)

# duplicate image and set a clip path
im2 = ax.imshow(imdata, extent=(0, 1, 0, 1), aspect='auto',
                cmap=cm.coolwarm, zorder=3)
im2.set_clip_path(minirect)

# add the text on top
text = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Text', fontsize='xx-large', fontweight='bold',
               color='k', ha='center', va='center', zorder=5)
```

[image]