# Fill area between two rectangles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use the following code to plot two rectangles.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


def main():
    # Box 1
    x1_1, y1_1 = 1.0, 2.0
    x1_2, y1_2 = 8.0, 9.0
    height1 = y1_2 - y1_1
    width1 = x1_2 - x1_1

    # Box 2
    x2_1, y2_1 = 3.0, 4.0
    x2_2, y2_2 = 7.0, 6.0
    height2 = y2_2 - y2_1
    width2 = x2_2 - x2_1

    # Plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
    ax.plot()
    rectangle1 = Rectangle(xy=(x1_1, y1_1), width=width1, height=height1, fill=False)
    rectangle2 = Rectangle(xy=(x2_1, y2_1), width=width2, height=height2, fill=False)
    ax.add_patch(rectangle1)
    ax.add_patch(rectangle2)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("box.png")
    plt.close(fig)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

In my case, the smaller rectangle is always inside the larger rectangle. I would like the fill the space between these two rectangles (blue shaded area above). How can I do this with Matplotlib? I tried Matplotlib's `fill_between` which seems to work only for curves defined by `x` and `y` coordinates. Is there maybe another approach how I can fill the space between two rectangles?

This plot is part of a larger plot with other objects. So I need a shaded area that can be transparent (parameter `alpha` smaller than 1) and the inner section to be completely invisible. Just adding a white rectangle onto the blue one does not help in my case.

Comment: You can use the `DoubleRect` function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622485/how-to-nicely-plot-clipped-layered-artists-in-matplotlib/33683718#33683718).

Answer (score 1):

If you draw the larger rectangle first (which it appears you do) I believe if you attempted to fill the boxes with colors it would do what you are asking. I added small changes to your code to do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


def main():
    # Box 1
    x1_1, y1_1 = 1.0, 2.0
    x1_2, y1_2 = 8.0, 9.0
    height1 = y1_2 - y1_1
    width1 = x1_2 - x1_1

    # Box 2
    x2_1, y2_1 = 3.0, 4.0
    x2_2, y2_2 = 7.0, 6.0
    height2 = y2_2 - y2_1
    width2 = x2_2 - x2_1

    # Plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
    ax.plot()
    # these 2 lines are the ones that were changed, notice the fill=True and color='*any color string*'
    rectangle1 = Rectangle(xy=(x1_1, y1_1), width=width1, height=height1, fill=True, color='blue')
    rectangle2 = Rectangle(xy=(x2_1, y2_1), width=width2, height=height2, fill=True, color='white')
    ax.add_patch(rectangle1)
    ax.add_patch(rectangle2)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("box.png")
    plt.close(fig)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You need to make it so the rectangle is filled so the inside is colored, then you can change the color parameter to be whatever you wish!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I updated my question. I forgot to mention, that I need the inner rectangle to be completely transparent.

Comment: What do you mean by transparent in this case? By inner rectangle, you mean the smaller one I figure, right? Just making sure, I believe there is a way to alter the transparency of the rectangles, but I would need to check.

Comment: I mean that it is basically a rectangle where a smaller rectangle is cut out somewhere inside the larger rectangle allowing other objects in the background to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

hatches = ['/']
def main():
    # Box 1
    x1_1, y1_1 = 1.0, 2.0
    x1_2, y1_2 = 8.0, 9.0
    height1 = y1_2 - y1_1
    width1 = x1_2 - x1_1

    # Box 2
    x2_1, y2_1 = 3.0, 4.0
    x2_2, y2_2 = 7.0, 6.0
    height2 = y2_2 - y2_1
    width2 = x2_2 - x2_1

    # Plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
    ax.plot()
    rectangle2 = Rectangle(xy=(x2_1, y2_1), width=width2, height=height2, edgecolor='black', facecolor='white')
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle(xy=(x1_1, y1_1), width=width1, height=height1, fill=False, hatch=hatches[0],color='blue'))
    ax.add_patch(rectangle2)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("box.png")
    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Reference [matplotlib.patches.Rectangle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html)

Comment: I need the area of the smaller rectangle to be completely invisible so that other objects in the plot can be visible. I updated my questions.

Comment: As my understanding, i haved added `alpha=0.2` (0.2 is simple preference from me) to the second rectangle

Comment: When I add `alpha=0.2` to your example, there are blue lines visible inside the smaller rectangle. However, I need the area of the smaller rectangle to be completely empty so that other objects in the plot are visible.

Comment: @Samuel, There is already one solution linked with the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use color argument as follows:

```
rectangle1 = Rectangle(xy=(x1_1, y1_1), width=width1, height=height1, color='blue')
rectangle2 = Rectangle(xy=(x2_1, y2_1), width=width2, height=height2, color='white')
```